# About using the progress bar in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I want to add a progress bar to my Winforms project, but I have a problem.

In this case it won't close after 2 seconds

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.ShowDialog();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        form1.Close();
    }
```

In this case the progress bar will not move

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        form1.Close();
    }
```

May I ask how to solve this problem? Or is there a better progress bar plug-in in Visual Studio?

Comment: Why have you posted the same text and code twice? Did the site tell you that you had not provided enough information and you decided to trick it by simply reposting the same thing again? In that case, maybe you should have shown the site and us enough respect to actually provide more information and make your question clearer, rather than making it harder to understand.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - one has form1.show, other form1.showdialog

Comment: you should not put the main thread to sleep like that, use a timer to fire an event after 2 seconds

Comment: @pm100, that is the case now but, originally, there were four code snippets and it was just those two repeated, along with the text above each. You can take a look at the history to see the edit. The fact that the duplicate text could be deleted without the site complaining suggests that maybe it wasn't done to get around that in the first place. The comment on my answer seems to suggest it was a mistake, so either the site went haywire in that moment or the OP made an error and didn't check the preview before submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jmcilhinney has already explained it very clearly, you need to understand the threading issues well.

Here is a method that does not need to use a timer, please refer to the following code:

```
         Form2 form2 = new Form2();
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         {
             form2.ShowDialog();
         });

         this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
         {
             if (form2 != null)
             {
                 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                 form2.Close();
                 form2.Dispose();
                 form2 = null;
             }
         }));
```

Comment: Great, this is what I wanted, thank you and jmcilhinney

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the code blocks at `ShowDialog` so the line to close the form can't be executed until the form is closed.

In the second case, you are sleeping the UI thread for 2 seconds and, at the same time, expecting the UI thread to update the `ProgressBar`. Can you do work while you're asleep?

The solution here is to use a `Timer` in the other form itself. Set its `Interval` to 2000 and then, in its `Tick` event handler, close the form. That way, you can call `ShowDialog` so that the first form is inaccessible but the second form will still close after 2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, don't know why some parts were restored again. I will try following your train of thought

Comment: @goog, we all make mistakes, or maybe the site just went haywire. Such repeated text is a red flag though, because the site will detect questions that don't appear to contain enough information and some people simply copy and paste their inadequate question multiple times to get around it. Your question was clear enough as it is but, if you ever do get that message, be sure to flesh out your description of the problem as intended. I have removed my down-vote on the assumption that it was not intentional.